# Image Quality degrading after getting bitmap from internet and setting it to a Image View

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am using a site which provides Json response(Imdb details ) if one gives A movie Title for a app - omdbapi.com

if movie name is Fury(2014)

the link- "omdbapi(dotcom)/?t=Fury&y=2014&plot=short&r=json"

The link for poster is : ia.media-imdb(dotcom)/images/M/MV5BMjA4MDU0NTUyN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzQxMzY4MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg

now if i change it to(See the last part [ 1920 ]  i get better quality ) :
ia.media-imdb(dotcom)/images/M/MV5BMjA4MDU0NTUyN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzQxMzY4MjE@._V1_SX1920.jpg

but the issue is image quality is very poor when i set the Bitmap to Image View (I am using library 
github(dotcom)/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view for pinch zoom effect on image view   ).

what should i do to get better quality images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library, as it has a lot of ways to manipulate the image. It can even cache images on memory and disk.