# get high quality picture from base64 string

Tags: php, android, image, bitmap

I'm returning image as `base64 string` in server side. In client side app *takes* this base64 string and convert it to `byte[]` and then to `Bitmap` and at the last step sets this bitmap to `ImageView`. My problem is *returned image quality*. It looks poor; I can see the pixels of this image...

#### Upload part

Client side (upload):

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 3;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, options);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
// Encode Image to String
encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
```

Server side (accepts uploaded image):

```
$_image = $_REQUEST['image'];
$binary = base64_decode($_image);
// for inserting it to db...
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (`_profile_pic`) VALUES ('$_image')";
$connect->query($sql);
```

#### Accept part

Server side (gets base64 string from db)

```
$user_data = "SELECT _name, _profile_pic FROM users WHERE _id = {$_id}";
$data = $connect->query($user_data);
while ($row = $data->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    $collectedResult[] = $row;
echo json_encode($collectedResult, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Client side (sets image to ImageView (problematic part) )

```
_picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_imageView);
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(profile_pic_value, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
_picture.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

At this moment I don't know how to *restore* or increase the quality.

Any helpful comment, answer appreciated.

Regards,
Mirjalal.

P.S This question maybe duplicate of another question(s), but I couldn't find duplicate one. :D 
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27721500/4057688) but I don't know how to use.

Comment: When you examined the image stored on your server, what did it look like (good or bad)? When you examined the image downloaded from your server (e.g., via a Web browser), what did it look like (good or bad)? Why are you wasting CPU, battery, and time decoding the bitmap only to re-encode the bitmap in the upload code, instead of just converting the image that you have on disk into base64? Why are you using base64 in the first place, instead of simply uploading and downloading the image directly?

Comment: The roundtrip from client to server and back to client does not change the data at all, so any quality loss is because of the initial compression.

Comment: @CommonsWare it looks bad after (when I'm *opening it* in browser).
I tried it, but I *failed*. And I couldn't find helpful code, because both image and other data load in the same web page. So, I couldn't get image and data separately. 
sorry for my English.

Comment: "it looks bad after (when I'm opening it in browser)" -- presumably, the problem lies in your upload code. I suggest that you change that code to convert the existing image into base64, rather than what you have now (decode the image, re-encode the image, and then convert the re-encoded image to base64).

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry but I'm confused :/ (brain stopped)

Comment: `imgPath` points to a file. This file contains an image. You do not need to decode this image to a `Bitmap`. You need to read in the bytes of that file and convert those bytes to base64.

Comment: I want to solve this problem like that: 
1) I'll replace the base64 string with the `imgPath + fileName` in db
2) when user login to his/her account app will search the file in specific folder (where I was store the copy of the image before uploading)
3) if image exits image'll load into imageView else handling this situation.
Is this eligible method ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you loose color depth during decoding into RAM. Android has defaults as to which color format it decodes bitmaps. See following example which saves RAM but still maintains acceptable image quality.

```
public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, Base64.DEFAULT);
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length, options);
}
```

Take a closer look at the `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this. But I *checked* the file after upload, the quality looks bad. As @CommonsWare said, my upload method (in client side) *lies me*.

Comment: As I said the problem in upload *section*. So, this is not helped me. Thanks.